# how to make a OK button in netbeans empty

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jbutton

I am entering a value into the OK button (Netbeans Jframe) by using this method:

```
    public void change (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
if (turn == true) {
    JButton button = (JButton) evt.getSource();
    button.setText("X");
    turn = false;
    button.setEnabled(false);
}
    else {
    JButton button = (JButton) evt.getSource();
    button.setText("O");
    turn = true;
    button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

I then later want to have a reset button that returns the value inside the OK button to nothing (so it is blank) i currently have the following but it does not work.

public void reset (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
if (reset == true)
{

    JButton button = (JButton) evt.getSource();
    button.setEnabled(true);
    button.setText("");
    turn = false;
}
```

what would be my code?

Comment: Your conditional statements are redundant. Could simply be `if(turn)` and `if(reset)`. Also, for better help sooner, include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 2):

Your code only resets the button which has been clicked :

```
JButton button = (JButton) evt.getSource();
```

You need to iterate through all the buttons to reset:

```
if (reset) {
    for (JButton button = buttonsToReset) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.setText("");
    }
    turn = false;
}
```

This code assumes that the buttons to reset are placed in a collection or array of buttons named `buttonsToReset`.

Comment: is there no easier way to use reset it? I'm using a jButton1 in netbeans so how would I write it?

Comment: My mind slipped and thought you had several buttons to reset (like in an OXO game). See my edited answer. jButton1 is an awful name. Rename your buttons to know who they are: okButton, resetButton instead of jButton1, jButton2.

Comment: i do i have 9 jButtons..so my code wil be like: for (int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)
    {
        int[] buttonsToReset = new int[8];
        buttonsToReset [i] = jButton[i];

Comment: Then my initial answer was correct. You shouldn't use Swing if you don't know how to use arrays. This is very basic stuff that you need to know. Your code creates 9 arrays of 8 elements instead of 1 array of 9 elements. And jButton[i] doesn't exist. If it existed, you would already have an array of buttons, and there would be no point in creating a new one.

Comment: i know how to use arrays but just started using swing about a week ago.

Comment: i tried to make this my array but it didn't work:  private JButton button_array [] = {jButton1, jButton2, jButton3, jButton4, jButton5, jButton6, jButton7, jButton8, jButton9};

Comment: *"it didn't work"* is the poorest problem description I can imagine. Elaborate.

Comment: i figured out the array now but  i can't compare the normal JButton with a JButton array. I tried this for my array                          private JButton[] button_array  =  {new JButton("1"),new JButton("2"),new JButton("3"),new JButton("4"),new JButton("5"),new JButton("6"),new JButton("7"),new JButton("8"),new JButton("9")};

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose anything with only one line of your code. Edit your question with a SSCCE.

Comment: this is how I'm trying to compare it                                 if (reset) {
    for (JButton button = button_array ) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.setText("");
    }
    turn = false;
}
    
    }

Comment: You still haven't posted an SSCCE, and you still haven't described what didn't work. Do that to get help.